# why domain is hashed in google analytics?

Tags: javascript, hash, web, google-analytics, web-analytics

I am building my own library for web analytics reference with [Google Analytics](http://www.google.co.in/analytics/), [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/).

In Google Analytics, the domain is hashed and this hash is stored in the [cookie](http://www.tutkiun.com/2011/04/a-google-analytics-cookie-explained.html).

I have found a similar hashing technique in the urchin tracker:

```
    function(d) {
      if (!d || d == "") return 1;
      var h = 0,
      g = 0;
      for (var i = d.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var c = parseInt(d.charCodeAt(i));
        h = ((h << 6) & 0xfffffff) + c + (c << 14);
        if ((g = h & 0xfe00000) != 0) h = (h ^ (g >> 21));
      }
      return h;
    }
```

Is there any specific reason for hashing the domain in google analytics or just for reference?

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it's to avoid storing "sensitive" (although not sure why that would matter here) information in a cookie?

Comment: @pst May be but one thing it can be unhashed.

Comment: A hash function - even a primitive one - is a one-way algorithm. It's not like encryption and it's generally impossible to reverse.

Comment: @pst I have found some technique for [reverse hashing](http://blog.distracted.nl/2009/04/reversing-cryptographic-hash.html)

Comment: It is impossible (without a constrained domain << range) to reverse a hash due to the [pigeon hole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: @pst ok i agree, thanks a lot for your information.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs for [`_setAllowHash()`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setAllowHash):

> The domain hashing functionality in Google Analytics creates a hash value from your domain, and uses this number to check cookie integrity for visitors.

Note that `_setAllowHash` has been deprecated -- I don't know if this means Google Analytics no longer uses domain hash for cookie validation or something else...

Comment: No, it still uses the hash. It's just that it's use is deprecated because disabling the hash (which was once a tactic to add cross-domain tracking) is no longer necessary. If you did want to disable the hash, you could enter `"none"` as your `_setDomainName` value and it has the same effect.